# Would Raspbian break if the extraneous locales were deleted from /usr/share/locales?

Tags: raspbian, locale, rsync

Rsync spends a lot of time (and bandwidth) backing up all the extraneous locales when a full system backup is performed.

It takes up a lot of disk space for features that will never be used on this system, which is based in the US.

Would it break Raspbian if all but the en directory were removed?

Comment: There is a package in Debian & Ubuntu repository (and therefore should be available on Raspbian via `apt`) called [`localepurge`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/localepurge) that should allow you do this ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477974/how-to-remove-unnecessary-locales#477981), [see also](https://askubuntu.com/q/58191/178596)). However, how are you doing the backup? You may be able to do it by just updating a copy of the existing backup with rsync as the locales shouldn't change much, though removing them will save space generally.

Comment: Interesting.  Will have a look.  As I run rsync backups of whole systems I notice also a lot of junk inside Chromium to support locales all over the world.  I'd like to get them out, too, if only to save disk space on both the primary SD cards and on the hard drive backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is not a good idea to turn **`localpurge`** loose on a nicely-tuned system.

It is too unpredictable and **yes it can break Raspbian**.  I had to re-image a SD card after running it, to start over.

Also, when using `--delete` and `--delete-excluded` options with rsync it minimizes the data transfers after the initial run.

So rsync basically has solved the problem after all was said and done.